# The requested URL could not be found for Django project while running on httpd server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

This post is a bit long. Those interested kindly bear with me on this one. 
I am running a Django project on apache2 server.
I have two images embedded in anchor tags in my index.html HTML page :

```
<a id="pop1" href="#"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuFkPwpxwXwgnnwvPHLxW1sCbtPKfqdpz6jApGYbEbeD99Ob-Z" width="30px" height="25px" style="margin-bottom:6px;"> </a>
```

and

```
<a align="right" id="pop2" href="#"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuFkPwpxwXwgnnwvPHLxW1sCbtPKfqdpz6jApGYbEbeD99Ob-Z" width="30px" height="25px" style="margin-bottom:6px;"> </a>
```

When I click on the images both open the same modal box. Below is the modal box code:

```
 <div id="alarmModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Shutdown Machines with less than certain % CPU Utilization after N minutes</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p> Please fill in the specifics below:</p>
                         <form id="alarm_form" action="/create_alarm/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                               <label for="period">Period of inactivity(in minutes):</label>
                              <input type="number" id="period" min="0" max="60" step="5" required>
                               <label for="cpu">CPU Utilization(in %):</label>
                              <input type="number" id="cpu" min="0" max="100" step="1" required>
            <br>
               <div id="alarmresult"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="btn btn-default" id="upload" type="submit" value="Optimize"></input>
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Ajax and Jquery code is pasted below :

```
function alarmfunc(){
//$('#pop1,#pop2').on('click', function(event){
//$('#alarmModal').modal('show');

//Submit Post on Submit

$('#alarm_form').on('submit', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
$('#optimize').attr("disabled",true);
 console.log("form submitted!");
 var period = $("#period").val();
 var cpu = $("#cpu").val();
 console.log(period,cpu)
//alert(form_data);
 $.ajax({
  url : "/cloud_alarm/",
  type : "POST",
  data : {period:period, cpu:cpu},
  cache: false,
 //handle a successful response
  success : function(result) {
      $("#alarmresult").empty();
      $('#optimize').removeAttr("disabled");
      console.log("success");
      $("#alarmresult").prepend("<br><p><span class='title'>CloudWatch Alarm Status: " + result + "</span></p>");
   },

 //handle a non-successful response
 error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
       $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>");
       console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
  }
});
});
}
}
```

In my urls.py I have pasted the below url :

```
 url(r'^home(?P<uid>[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20})/cloud_alarm/', views.cloud_alarm, name="cloudalarm"),
```

Finally my views.py function is below :

```
def cloud_alarm(request,uid):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    period = request.POST['period']
    #ins_id = request.POST['insid']
    cpu = request.POST['cpu']
    period = int((period) * 60)
    starter_pack_accnum =293952640683
    try:
      cloudwatch=boto3.client('cloudwatch',region_name='us-west-2')
      cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm(
       AlarmName='Alarm_'+ str(insid),
       ComparisonOperator='LessThanThreshold',
       EvaluationPeriods=5,
       MetricName='CPUUtilization',
       Namespace='AWS/EC2',
       Period= period,
       Statistic='Average',
       Threshold=30.0,
       ActionsEnabled=True,
       AlarmDescription='Alarm when server CPU falls below 30%',
       Dimensions=[
       {
        'Name': 'InstanceId',
        'Value': ins_id
       },
      ],
       AlarmActions=['arn:aws:swf:us-west-2:' + str(starter_pack_accnum) + ':action/actions/AWS_EC2.InstanceId.Stop/1.0'],
       Unit= 'Percent',
       )
      result = "The CloudWatch Alarm," + str(AlarmName) + "has been created for this instance for the optimization process."
    except Exception as e:
      result = "An unexpected error occurred while creating the CloudWAtch alarm" + str(AlarmName) + "for this instance."

   return HttpResponse(result)
```

But when I try to submit the form it is redirecting to :
        "**The requested URL could not be found**"

What am I doing wrong here ? Is there a problem in passing values from the modal form to the ajax ? I am a little beginner in this. Any help will be appreciated.
Please help.

Comment: I tried adding /home/uid/cloud_alarm to form action but that doesn't work either

Comment: You are missing a slash in the url pattern, so it’s currently matching `/homeabcd/cloud_alarm/` instead of `/home/abcd/cloud_alarm/`. The slash at the end of the form action is important as well - `/home/uid/cloud_alarm` without a trailing slash won’t work for post requests.

Comment: Okay. Do I need to change it in form action as well as in ajax url ?

Comment: @Alasdair I am getting server error (500) now

Comment: 500 server error is not enough information to help. You need to update your question with the exact code that causes the error and the full traceback. You might find it easier if you get this code working on a local development environment with `runserver` and `DEBUG=True`. Then deploy to Apache when it’s working.

Answer (score 0):

You did not submit request to correct url
change the code as below example. It will work.

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^cloud_alarm/$', views.cloud_alarm, name="cloudalarm"),
```

**views.py**

```
def cloud_alarm(request):
   # your code
```

Comment: I am getting Server Error 500 now

Comment: Is there something wrong with my ajax response code ? i'm not sure if the values are getting passed to the views function or not. I guess the error is probably in the ajax, jquery code.

Comment: @SiddharthSingh  share(update in the question) the error  that's showing on your terminal/cmd

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form from:

```
<form id="alarm_form" action="/create_alarm/" method="POST">
```

to:

```
<form id="alarm_form" action="{% url 'app_name:cloudalarm' uid %}" method="POST">
```

It looks like your form action isn't getting the uid passed. I don't know what you have *app_name* defined to in urls.py so you'll need to change "app_name" to whatever your appname is. Make sure you are defining your app name inside of urls.py as seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names).